# Angularjs ui-select (select2) not working with 'Controller as' syntax not getting selected ite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, angularjs-select2, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to get a select HTML control working with AngularJS ui-select which is located [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) on GitHub. For some reason, I am able to get the item selected when using $scope syntax, but not when I use the Controller As syntax. The plunker I am trying to get working with Controller as syntax is located [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zPZKINjRqI2EtZJlfKVS?p=preview). I'm not sure what I am missing especially since the $scope syntax works perfectly.

I'm not getting any errors to report. Here is a snippet from what is in plunker.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
```

app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);

```
function MainCtrl()
{
  var controller = this;

  controller.person = {};
  controller.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 10 },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30 },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 31 },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54 },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43 },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21 }
  ];

}
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <h3>Select2 theme</h3>
    <p>Selected: {{vm.person.selected}}</p>
    <ui-select ng-model="person.selected.name" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in vm.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small>
            email: {{person.email}}
            age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing all of your scripts to work with `https` rather than `http` (requirement for plunker) and changing `ng-model="person.selected.name"` to `ng-model="vm.person.selected.name"`, the ControllerAs version works perfectly with no further adjustments.

https://plnkr.co/edit/2VtUefWPKdBVaqY1gU66?p=preview

Comment: Interesting Claies. I knoew about plunkers requirements, but i must have completely forgotten to add the vm back in. Thank you for updating it.

Comment: Long time no see... @Claies

Answer (score 0):

The name used as an alias for `controller` in the `HTML` should be the same name of the varibale referred in `Javascript` file too. Plus, you are missing the scope in method `MainCtrl()`.
So here, in your case the variable in JS should be `vm`. You can refer an example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/s8kLdw1m/).

Please find the updated code below.

**Javascript**

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.person = {};
    vm.people = [
      { name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 10 },
      { name: 'Amalie', email: 'amalie@email.com', age: 12 },
      { name: 'Wladimir', email: 'wladimir@email.com', age: 30 },
      { name: 'Samantha', email: 'samantha@email.com', age: 31 },
      { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefanía@email.com', age: 16 },
      { name: 'Natasha', email: 'natasha@email.com', age: 54 },
      { name: 'Nicole', email: 'nicole@email.com', age: 43 },
      { name: 'Adrian', email: 'adrian@email.com', age: 21 }
    ];
    $scope = vm;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Shashank I thought using the controller as syntax with an alternative to using $scope? I'm guessing that is incorrect? Also, I have read a few times now that $scope was going away in a new version of Angular? Is that false?

Comment: There is no problem in using `controller as` syntax. But there should be a way for `$scope` to inject so as to exploit `dependency-injection`, otherwise how would the controller know the `scope` and how the models would bind between `controllers` and `model`. I don't know whether `scopes` are going away or not. Need to research it out.

Comment: -I see what you are saying about 'how does it know', but since I'm new to angular, I guess based on everything I have been reading, the 'controller as' syntax is just that, syntactical sugar. usually, in my experience, syntactical sugar just means shorter or easier to read code "without" loss of functionality. Here are some examples of what I have been reading: 
https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/07/02/exploring-angular-s-controller-as-syntax-and-the-vm-variable.aspx
Thoughts??

Comment: any thoughts on those links @Shashank ? I don't see any of them reference $scope?

Comment: setting `$scope = vm` isn't something that makes sense with the newer releases of angular 1.3+.  In fact, using `$scope = vm` can cause unexpected complications with the automatic scope inheritance in angular.  It was a workaround before `ControllerAs` was added, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: gcoleman0828 yeah I have gone through those links and it is helpful as I was not aware of it. @Claies thankx for the knowledge info.

Comment: @gcoleman0828, as far as `$scope` is concerned it's OK, but what about other dependency injections such as `$location, $rootScope, $window, etc`, how can one replace those in the new AngularJS versions?

Comment: @Shashank as far as I understand angulars (which I'l admit is still very new to me), $window, $location etc are seperate services and will still need to be injected the same as previous AngularJS versions. It is just $scope that is going away completely. That 'service' is being depreicated. Is that accurate @Claies?

Comment: the `$scope` service isn't deprecated in angular 1.x, it merely has been given an alternative format to provide for easier transition to angular 2.  Angular 2 is a complete rewrite from the ground up, and none of the existing features operate in the same manner.  You *can* still inject `$scope` when necessary (broadcasts, for example), but using ControllerAs gives you the option not to use it for **every** situation.

Comment: it is interesting, however, that the comments around an answer have evolved into another question....